# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' using google play ads servies

Tags: android, exception, keyboard, build.gradle

I am trying to add the google play services for admob to my Android Studio project, however when I try to run the app, it keeps failing with 1 error.So i dont really know whats going wrong?

```
    this is Error:

    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable730Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65540 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:72)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:49)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:842)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:813)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:785)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:682)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:542)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 35.156 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

    ===========================================================================
    My Gradle file is:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.keyboard"
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 2

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

    }
    ==============================================================
    this is my Manifest File:

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.keyboard"
        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.1">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21"
            />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/roman"
            android:theme="@style/keyboard_1_style"
            android:label="@string/ime_name"

            >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.keyboard.help"
                android:label="Example Keypad">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name=".Help"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service android:name="SoftKeyboard"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.view.im"
                    android:resource="@xml/method" />
            </service>


            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
                />

            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
                >

            </activity>



        </application>
    </manifest>
```

If someone could please give me a few pointers as to where i am going wrong, i would be immensivly grateful.

Comment: Could you detail what exact error are you getting?

Comment: ok i edit my error part.

Comment: At a certain point, there is a limit of methods : see there : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup at Selectively compiling APIs into your executable

Comment: i have already tried out this link. but this doesn't helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building Apps with Over 65K Methods:

you can use the multidex support library for that, To enable multidex

1) include it in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

2) Enable it in your app:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

3) if you have a application class for your app then Override the attachBaseContext method like this:

package ....;
...
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  ....
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

4) if you don't have a application class for your application then register android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication as your application in your manifest file. like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

and it should work fine!

Comment: Hey Buddy, One thing More! Always Updated your Android Studio.